# How are Dramatists' grouped characters supposed to work?

Tags: dramatist

So I'm confused about the syntax of grouped characters (described in section 2.4.1 of [the 2014-12-18 version of the user's guide](http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/dramatist/dramatist.pdf)). The guide says the following:

> Inside this environment the char- acters have to be defined by `\GCharacter` whose syntax is the same of `\Character`, except that the first argument is here, obviously, mandatory. The result will be that the characters will be grouped by a big parentheses on whose right will be printed, centered, the common denomination.

I assumed that this was intended to, for instance, allow for "groups" of characters like we see in [*Hamlet*'s Dramatis Personae](https://www.owleyes.org/text/hamlet/read/dramatis-personae):

```
Players:
     Two Clowns, gravediggers
     A Norwegian Captain
     English Ambassadors
     Lords, Ladies, Officers, Soldiers, Sailors, Messengers, Attendants
```

So I tried doing what I think was described.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{dramatist}

\GCharacter[Players]{Two Clowns, gravediggers}{clowns}
\GCharacter[Players]{A Norwegian Captain}{captain}
\GCharacter[Players]{English Ambassadors}{ambassadors}
\GCharacter[Players]{Lords, Ladies, Officers, Soldiers, Sailors, Messengers, Attendants}{others}

\begin{document}

\DramPer

\end{document}
```

However, this resulted in the following error when I tried compiling with `pdflatex`:

```
! LaTeX Error: No counter 'gVII' defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.4 \GCharacter[Pl
                   ayers]{Two Clowns, gravediggers}{clowns}
?
```

What is the proper usage of grouped characters? Am I understanding the reason someone would want to use it, and if so, what about the syntax am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 3):

You need to surround your characters with the `CharacterGroup` environment, like so:

```
\begin{CharacterGroup}{Players}
    \GCharacter{Two Clowns, gravediggers}{clowns}{clowns}
    \GCharacter{A Norwegian Captain}{captain}{capt}
    \GCharacter{English Ambassadors}{ambassadors}{ambs}
    \GCharacter{Lords, Ladies, Officers, Soldiers, Sailors, Messengers, Attendants}{others}{other}
\end{CharacterGroup}
```

The first argument to `\GCharacter` is required.  But other than that, the command works just like `\Character`

Comment: Welcome to this site!

Comment: Thank you kindly.